# How do I define a collections of commands for later use？

Tags: functions

Many ask me to tackle this problem by making another function(subroutine) of the lines I want to pick out, using

> Block,Module,etc

The problem is different here.Notice that Block and Module defines some local variables and calculate the expression given, But here my lines ARE NOT variables, they are commands, so it still won't work by thinking these commands as some function while you might input something to it and create something else. I don't kown, these lines I want to pick out are like a pipe, datas really want to go in and come out, but it's structure isn't that complex as a subroutine maybe? Forgive me for such silly question, but now it seems my code has changed, instead of pick out those lines that I want to use many times at different ODE solvers, now I combine those solvers into one sigle more huge solver, it turns out this way is more sufficient. But thank you for those replied and fine sugestions.Any way, this question still remains open:

> How can we pick out a collections of commands, pack them together and call it where ever we want to use it?

Here is the original question:
I wrote some functions （my RungerKutta function ），in order to simplify the
question，I give an example as below:

```
RK2op[f_, {x0_, xn_}, y0_, h_] := 
Block[{xold = x0, yold = y0, sollist = {{x0, y0}}, x, y, n, steps,xnew,ynew,xthird,fn,k1}, 
steps = Round[(xn - x0)/h];
Do[xnew = xold + h;
xthird = xold + 2*h/3;
fn = f [x -> xold, yold];
k1 = f[xthird, yold + fn*2*h/3];
ynew = yold + h*fn/4 + 3*h*k1/4;
sollist = Append[sollist, {xnew, ynew}];
xold = xnew;
yold = ynew, {steps}];
Return[sollist[[steps + 1]]]]
```

Now if I want to pick out some lines out of this function, and define those lines as a collection, replace those lines by a name, so I can use those collection of commands(lines) as whole, namely I can simply call the name of this "pack" of lines so to make my function look a little cleaner, how can I do it?i.e. I tried:

```
collection=xnew = xold + h;
xthird = xold + 2*h/3;
fn = f [x -> xold, yold];
k1 = f[xthird, yold + fn*2*h/3];
ynew = yold + h*fn/4 + 3*h*k1/4;
sollist = Append[sollist, {xnew, ynew}];
xold = xnew;
yold = ynew
```

then I wrote

```
RK2op[f_, {x0_, xn_}, y0_, h_] := 
Block[{xold = x0, yold = y0, sollist = {{x0, y0}}, x, y, n, steps,xnew,ynew,xthird,fn,k1}, 
steps = Round[(xn - x0)/h];
Do[collection, {steps}];
Return[sollist[[steps + 1]]]]
```

But this simply can't help, Can anyone help me on this?(The reason I want to have this collection is because I want to use these lines in other places many times).

Comment: ...then why not write `collection` as a function with appropriate inputs (i.e. a *subroutine*), just like what you did with `RK2op`?

Comment: By the way, I would expect a pack of lines to be usesd at many place in whole program, so this simple pack should not influence the calculation at other places, anyway,I don't kown,maybe when the program becomes large, some words might overlap, miss called or some thing like that....

Comment: All the more that you should write it as a subroutine, then.

Comment: I should try to figure this out, thank you for your suggestion@J. M.♦

Comment: Take a look at the section in the documentation entitled [Defining Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).

Comment: OK，Thanks :) @ WReach